# Trying to install qt-pods on windows

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

Im trying to install qt-pods on windows.
I downloaded the qt-pods package from github to my pc.

then i went into the folder and tried to run `qmake && make`.

the `qmake` succeed with no errors (i did it also alone for checking) but the 'make' threw me the following errors:

```
...a lot of errors like this...
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.text$_ZN10PodManagerD0Ev[_ZN10PodManagerD0Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QObjectD2Ev'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7QObject16staticMetaObjectE'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10PodManager[_ZTV10PodManager]+0x38): undefined reference to `QObject::event(QEvent*)'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10PodManager[_ZTV10PodManager]+0x40): undefined reference to `QObject::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10PodManager[_ZTV10PodManager]+0x48): undefined reference to `QObject::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10PodManager[_ZTV10PodManager]+0x50): undefined reference to `QObject::childEvent(QChildEvent*)'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10PodManager[_ZTV10PodManager]+0x58): undefined reference to `QObject::customEvent(QEvent*)'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10PodManager[_ZTV10PodManager]+0x60): undefined reference to `QObject::connectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)'
F:\Users\matan_000\Documents\Programming\c++-libraries\qt-pods\qt-pods-core\release/libqt-pods-core.a(moc_podmanager.o):moc_podmanager.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV10PodManager[_ZTV10PodManager]+0x68): undefined reference to `QObject::disconnectNotify(QMetaMethod const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile.Release:87: release\qt-pods-gui.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'F:/Users/matan_000/Documents/Programming/c++-libraries/qt-pods/qt-pods-gui'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:36: release] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'F:/Users/matan_000/Documents/Programming/c++-libraries/qt-pods/qt-pods-gui'
make: *** [Makefile:95: sub-qt-pods-gui-make_first] Error 2
```

and a lot of errors like this before...

Im almost hopeless...
I will be happy to help! thank you! :)